# I've got Discord V14 and I try to run embeds or get a message to delete itself and nothing but errors

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Code below; I've got the right Schema but this command will not pay out people with the loan and delete the message, nor will it allow embeds with buttons without sprouting an error. Code below. Any help would be appreciated:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
const { Message } = require("discord.js");

function purgeMessage(msg) {
  if (msg instanceof Message && msg.deletable) msg.delete().catch(() => null);
}

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("offerloan")
    .setDescription("Offer a loan to another user")
    .addUserOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("user")
        .setDescription("The user to offer the loan to")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addIntegerOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("amount")
        .setDescription("The amount of XP to loan")
        .setRequired(true)
        .setMinValue(1)
    )
    .addIntegerOption(
      (option) =>
        option
          .setName("interest")
          .setDescription("The interest rate for the loan (in percentage)")
          .setRequired(true)
          .setMinValue(0)
          .setMaxValue(15) // Set maximum interest rate to 15%
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const lenderId = interaction.user.id;
    const lenderMember = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(lenderId);
    const lenderGlobalName = lenderMember
      ? lenderMember.displayName || interaction.user.username
      : interaction.user.username;
    const borrowerId = interaction.options.getUser("user").id;
    const borrower = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(borrowerId);
    const borrowerGlobalName = borrower
      ? borrower.displayName || borrower.user.username
      : interaction.options.getUser("user").username;
    const amount = interaction.options.getInteger("amount");
    const interestRate = interaction.options.getInteger("interest");

    try {
      // Check if lender is trying to loan to themself
      if (lenderId === borrowerId) {
        return interaction.reply({
          content: "You cannot loan to yourself.",
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }

      // Check if lender has sufficient XP for the loan
      const lenderProfile = await profileModel.findOne({ userId: lenderId });
      if (!lenderProfile || lenderProfile.XP < amount) {
        return interaction.reply({
          content: "You don't have enough XP to offer this loan.",
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }

      // Deduct loan amount from lender's XP
      lenderProfile.XP -= amount;
      await lenderProfile.save();

      // Record the loan in the database for borrower
      await profileModel.updateOne(
        { userId: borrowerId },
        {
          $push: {
            loans: {
              loanerId: lenderId,
              loanerGlobalName: lenderGlobalName,
              loaneeId: borrowerId,
              loaneeGlobalName: borrowerGlobalName,
              loanAmount: amount,
              totalRepayment: amount + (amount * interestRate) / 100,
              interestRate: interestRate,
              accepted: false,
            },
          },
        },
        { upsert: true }
      );

      // Send a message in the channel to confirm the loan
      const channel = interaction.channel;
      const confirmMessage = await channel.send(
        `**${borrowerGlobalName}**, you've been offered a loan of ${amount} XP from **${lenderGlobalName}** with an interest rate of ${interestRate}%. Do you accept?`
      );

      // Add reactions for borrower to accept or decline the loan
      await confirmMessage.react("✅"); // Accept
      await confirmMessage.react("❌"); // Decline

      // Create a filter function to check for reactions by the borrower only
      const filter = (reaction, user) =>
        (reaction.emoji.name === "✅" || reaction.emoji.name === "❌") &&
        user.id === borrowerId &&
        user.id !== interaction.client.user.id; // Exclude bot reactions

      // Create a collector for reactions
      const collector = confirmMessage.createReactionCollector({
        filter,
        time: 15000, // 15 seconds
      });

      // Listen for reactions
      collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
        // Stop collecting reactions
        collector.stop();

        // Handle borrower's response
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
          // Borrower accepted the loan
          // Update loan status to accepted
          await profileModel.updateOne(
            { userId: borrowerId, "loans.loanerId": lenderId },
            { $set: { "loans.$.accepted": true } }
          );

          // Update borrower's XP with loan amount
          const borrowerProfile = await profileModel.findOne({
            userId: borrowerId,
          });
          borrowerProfile.XP += amount;
          await borrowerProfile.save();

          // Update lender's XP with loan amount
          lenderProfile.XP -= amount;
          await lenderProfile.save();

          await interaction.reply({
            content: `Loan of ${amount} XP offered to ${borrowerGlobalName} has been accepted.`,
          });

          // Remove the confirm message
          purgeMessage(confirmMessage);
        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌") {
          // Borrower declined the loan
          await interaction.reply({
            content: `${borrowerGlobalName} has declined the loan offer.`,
          });

          // Remove the confirm message
          purgeMessage(confirmMessage);
        }
      });

      // Handle collector timeout
      collector.on("end", async (collected, reason) => {
        if (reason === "time") {
          // If the collector times out, inform the lender
          await interaction.reply({
            content:
              "The loan offer has expired as there was no response from the borrower.",
          });

          // Remove the confirm message
          purgeMessage(confirmMessage);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error offering loan:", error);
      return interaction.reply({
        content: "An error occurred while processing your request.",
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }
  },
};
```

I've tried stopping the command listening, stopping the self delete, I've tried embeds but nothing seems to work.